# Fail to connect with Firebase [IOS/Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I encountered a weird problem trying to connect with firebase in my project. I already followed all necessary steps - firebase config, cocopod, google.plist - but I keep getting these error messages in this screenshot. Does anyone else encounter this problem and how did you resolve it?

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMRQB.jpg)

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Console

```
2020-10-25 10:47:24.604330-0400 test2[2991:35955] Connection 1: received failure notification
2020-10-25 10:47:24.604477-0400 test2[2991:35955] Connection 1: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2020-10-25 10:47:24.604584-0400 test2[2991:35955] Connection 1: encountered error(1:61)
2020-10-25 10:47:24.609628-0400 test2[2991:35955] Task <EF95DB6A-2445-4E58-9B2F-AFA35EE0A68E>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2020-10-25 10:47:24.616313-0400 test2[2991:35955] Task <EF95DB6A-2445-4E58-9B2F-AFA35EE0A68E>.<1> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600001748c90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
2020-10-25 10:47:24.645716-0400 test2[2991:35949] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2020-10-25 10:47:24.649697-0400 test2[2991:35949] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo.gl/)
2020-10-25 10:47:24.651125-0400 test2[2991:35955] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023171] Resetting App Measurement data
2020-10-25 10:47:24.752809-0400 test2[2991:35975] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-25 10:47:24.788481-0400 test2[2991:35949] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-10-25 10:47:24.789629-0400 test2[2991:35949] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-10-25 10:47:39.183384-0400 test2[2991:36053] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2020-10-25 10:47:39.183765-0400 test2[2991:36053] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(726) [0x7fd4bee004a0] handshake failed at state 0
2020-10-25 10:47:39.185931-0400 test2[2991:36053] Connection 3: received failure notification
2020-10-25 10:47:39.186090-0400 test2[2991:36053] Connection 3: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2020-10-25 10:47:39.186224-0400 test2[2991:36053] Connection 3: encountered error(1:61)
2020-10-25 10:47:39.190919-0400 test2[2991:36053] Task <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2020-10-25 10:47:39.192171-0400 test2[2991:35790] Task <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001732970 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>"), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2020-10-25 10:47:39.194966-0400 test2[2991:36054] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -1004, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001732970 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>"), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2020-10-25 10:47:39.197349-0400 test2[2991:36054] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023128] Network request failed to fetch remote config. Code, Error: 0, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001732970 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>"), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2020-10-25 10:47:39.198538-0400 test2[2991:36054] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023129] Network fetch failed. Will retry later. Code, error: 0, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001732970 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDownloadTask <69F833DC-E03D-46E7-A72D-DE7246C8BDFF>.<1>"), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:955410733527:ios:c82bc7afb517ae10479392?platform=ios&app_instance_id=3A4D3A72AC624838AB769B6871063F58&gmp_version=60900, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- I think everything is going well but it's appearing in the error that you may have a poor connection " Could not connect to the server "
My advice is to try it again and make sure from google Plist that it's documented under the same bundle identifier

2- If the previous doesn't work, just try to update the pod

3- In the worst case try to uninstall it & install it again